# Workflow for modifying an hdf5 file in vaex

Tags: python, vaex

As sort of follow on to my previous question [1], is there a way to open a hdf5 dataset in vaex, perform operations and then store the results to the same dataset?

I tried the following:

```
import vaex as vx

vxframe = vx.open('somedata.hdf5')
vxframe = some_transformation(vxframe)
vxframe.export_hdf5('somedata.hdf5')
```

This results in the error `OSError: Unable to create file (unable to truncate a file which is already open)`, so `h5py` can't write to the file while it is open. Is there another workflow to achieve this? I can write to another file as a workaround, but that seems quite inefficient as (I imagine) it has to copy all the data that has not changed as well.

[1] [Convert large hdf5 dataset written via pandas/pytables to vaex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264275/convert-large-hdf5-dataset-written-via-pandas-pytables-to-vaex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying to a new file would not be less efficient than writing to itself (at least not for this example), since it will have to write the same amount of bytes. I also would not recommend it, since if you make a mistake, you will mess up your data.

Exporting data is actually quite efficient, but even better, you can also choose to just export the columns you want:

```
df = vaex.open('somedata.hdf5')
df2 = some_transformation(df)
df2[['new_column1', 'new_columns2']].export('somedata_extra.hdf5')
...
# next time
df = vaex.open('somedata.hdf5')
df2 = vaex.open('somedata_extra.hdf5')
df = df.join(df2)  # merge without column name will merge on rows basis
```

We used this approach alot, to create auxiliary datasets on disk that were precomputed. Joining them back (on row bases) is instant, it does not take any time or memory.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting back so late but I always get a `AttributeError: 'Hdf5MemoryMapped' object has no attribute 'merge'` when i do this.

Comment: That should have been `join`, merge does not exist, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you can also do

```df = vaex.open('somedata*.hdf5')```

which will automatically open and combine the files.